# How to show the Item Total using ASP.NET Eval instead of ModelBinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and I am using ASP.NET 4.5. I am struggling right now with converting a statement from using a ModelBinding to Eval as I am using ObjectDataSource.

The ASP.NET line of code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#: String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice)))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

instead of using ModelBinding and saying Item.Quantity or Item.Product.UnitPrice, I would like to use Eval statement as this line of code is included in ASP.NET GridView which is bound to ObjectDatasSource. So how can I do that?

I tried to do it as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity").ToString()))  %>
 *  
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TTSF_Product.UnitPrice").ToString()))  %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

but unfortunately it gave me the following result:

> $4.00 * $22.50

instead of doing the mathematical calculation and I don't why. **So how can I fix that line of code?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do math operation with two string values here:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity").ToString()))  %>
 *  
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TTSF_Product.UnitPrice").ToString()))  %>
```

Try something like this:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", (Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TTSF_Product.UnitPrice") * Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity")).ToString()))  %>
```

Comment: thanks for your help and explanation. I tried your suggested solution but it didn't work with me at the beginning. Then, after modifying it a little bit, it worked with me. The right line of code is: `<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity").ToString()) *  Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TTSF_Product.UnitPrice").ToString()))  %>`

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me..

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity").ToString()) * Double.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TTSF_Product.UnitPrice").ToString())) %>
```